# Select multiple item in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

His guys im using nested recycler view for showing my list.
in that im showing a large list which has more than 3000, item in single array
here's the example of json:

```
    [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "perant_type_name": "Bench Press",
    "base_value": "229",
    "exercise": [
      {
        "exercise_id": "207",
        "exercise_name": " Run - 2000 m",
        "exercise_type": "Body Weight",
        "gym_account_id": "15",
        "last_modify_time": "2019-07-22 22:29:26",
        "exercise_type_id": "1",
        "exercise_video_link": "http://godspeed.itechs.co.in/godspeed/assets/video/exercise_5bdc33e1ea7b6.mp4",
        "exercise_percentage": "120",
        "id": "1",
        "perant_type_name": "Bench Press",
        "base_value": "229",
        "sets": [
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "18",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Reps",
            "tempo": "0",
            "weight": "0",
            "reps": "0",
            "gym_account_id": "0",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-11-05 06:02:00"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "18",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Reps",
            "tempo": "0",
            "weight": "0",
            "reps": "0",
            "gym_account_id": "0",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-11-05 06:02:00"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "6",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Sets",
            "tempo": "4",
            "weight": "4",
            "reps": "4",
            "gym_account_id": "16",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-07-20 03:18:29"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "6",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Sets",
            "tempo": "4",
            "weight": "4",
            "reps": "4",
            "gym_account_id": "16",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-07-20 03:18:29"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "5",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Weight",
            "tempo": "4",
            "weight": "4",
            "reps": "4",
            "gym_account_id": "16",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-07-20 03:18:19"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "5",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Weight",
            "tempo": "4",
            "weight": "4",
            "reps": "4",
            "gym_account_id": "16",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-07-20 03:18:19"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exercise_id": "207",
        "exercise_name": " Run - 2000 m",
        "exercise_type": "Body Weight",
        "gym_account_id": "15",
        "last_modify_time": "2019-07-22 22:29:26",
        "exercise_type_id": "1",
        "exercise_video_link": "http://godspeed.itechs.co.in/godspeed/assets/video/exercise_5bdc33e1ea7b6.mp4",
        "exercise_percentage": "120",
        "id": "1",
        "perant_type_name": "Bench Press",
        "base_value": "229",
        "sets": [
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "18",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Reps",
            "tempo": "0",
            "weight": "0",
            "reps": "0",
            "gym_account_id": "0",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-11-05 06:02:00"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "18",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Reps",
            "tempo": "0",
            "weight": "0",
            "reps": "0",
            "gym_account_id": "0",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-11-05 06:02:00"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "6",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Sets",
            "tempo": "4",
            "weight": "4",
            "reps": "4",
            "gym_account_id": "16",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-07-20 03:18:29"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "6",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Sets",
            "tempo": "4",
            "weight": "4",
            "reps": "4",
            "gym_account_id": "16",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-07-20 03:18:29"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "5",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Weight",
            "tempo": "4",
            "weight": "4",
            "reps": "4",
            "gym_account_id": "16",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-07-20 03:18:19"
          },
          {
            "exercise_sets_id": "5",
            "exercise_id": "0",
            "set_name": "Weight",
            "tempo": "4",
            "weight": "4",
            "reps": "4",
            "gym_account_id": "16",
            "last_modify_time": "2018-07-20 03:18:19"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

list have more than 5000 item in single array so it so hard select single item in it . whenever im selecting an like this

```
    exerciseforSearch.get(position).setSelectedExercise(true);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after notifyDataSetChanged list will be reRender and it so laggy when it select and item.
 how can I select an item without refreshing full list.

and im also using this `notifyItemChanged(position);` but it also doing the same thing list will become laggy how can I update only single item

and how can I implement sticky header in it ….
thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to store select index to previous index and change setSelectedExercise(false) and select index to setSelectedExercise(true)

Comment: Add filter or search option. Show 10 - 20 records only that user searched